# Angular 8: ternary operation for img src attribute?

Tags: javascript, angular

My data has a property "photo", which may be empty or contain a file name.

For example, "steve.jpg" or "" if steve has no photo.

In React JSX I could use a ternary operator on the value of "photo", but I don't know how to do it with Angular 8.

In know I could use 2 image tags with 2 `ngIf`s, but I'd like ot make it more dry.  This doesn't work for me at all:

```
<img[attr.src]="person.photo !=='' ? '/assets/images/people/{{person.photo}}' : '/assets/images/people/missing-person.jpg'">
```

Comment: Have you tried to do this without the `attr.` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's just [src] in angular, and the {{ }} syntax isn't valid in bindings. Only in interpolation, just access the variables like normal

```
<img [src]="person.photo !=='' ? '/assets/images/people/' + person.photo : '/assets/images/people/missing-person.jpg'">
```

Comment: it would not need it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like :

```
<img src="/assets/images/people/{{ (person.photo !=='' ? person.photo : 'missing-person') + '.jpg'}}">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).